# Why doesn't the loop iterate over the dynamic stored deserialized JSON values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

```
 dynamic ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(us.Value);
 foreach (int Id in ids)
 {
    int IdRet = Id;
    var v = db.subs.where(s=> s.Id == IdRet).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

Now the **db** is storing a serialized value like this 1 or 2 or 3.

I am trying to loop over it but throws error.

**"Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'"**

update:

us.Value is jus a plain 1 which was serialized and stored in the db. but later could be more.

Comment: Can you attach the json value for `us.Value` to the question?

Comment: Seems to me like ids is a number not a collection? In that case, use a simple "for" loop instead of "foreach".

Comment: us.Value is jus a plain 1 which was serialized and stored in the db.

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic` to solve a problem, you create yourself 2 or more (harder to solve) problems

Comment: @TheGeneral hi, so what is recommended? in this case.

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TheActualType>(us.Value)`

Comment: @TheGeneral put in answers i will accept. Thanks alot.